# Definition question of convex orbit of finite group action

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, definition, riemannian-geometry

Assume that a finite group or discrete group $G$ acts on a manifold $M$.

Here what does it mean that orbit $G\cdot x$ is convex ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Like a convex function (of $\,x\,$ ) , perhaps? ...

Comment: That the orbit is a convex subset.

Comment: You can define a convex *subgroup* of $G$ using its action on a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has been clarified that the question arose in the context of the paper *Structure of fundamental groups of manifolds with Ricci curvature bounded below* by Vitali Kapovitch and Burkhard Wilking. In the context of the paper, it seems that the authors use convexity in the following sense:

> A metric space $X$ is convex if for any two points $x,y\in X$ and any $\lambda\in [0,1]$ there exists a point $z\in X$ such that $d(x,z)=\lambda\, d(x,y)$ and $d(y,z)=(1-\lambda)\, d(x,y)$.

A subset of a metric space is convex if it's a convex metric space with the restriction metric. This property is sometimes called *metric convexity*, but be aware that this terminology is inconsistent in the literature.

In the proof of Gap Lemma in the paper the authors disprove the convexity of a particular set (an orbit) by  showing that it contains to points $z$ with $d(z,o)<0.51$ and $d(z,go)<0.51$, where $o$ and $go$ are two elements of the set with distance $1$ between them.

Then  they arrive at contradiction by showing that orbits are actually of the form $\{v\}\times Z$ and therefore convex; I could not follow this claim because I can't see what $Z$  is  on page 11.

In any event, the group whose orbits are considered here is obtained from discrete group by a limiting process; it need not be discrete itself.

Comment: The link is http://www.math.toronto.edu/vtk/margulis-final-up-10-29.pdf  In page 11, we can see several times "convex" in the proof of Gap Lemma.

Comment: @user37116 But I don't think that $K$ is finite or discrete there... it comes from a limit process. I'll update my answer, though.